# Javascript if / else not working properly [Time Formatting AM/PM]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have a div show the current time but it always shows it in military time, so I went to use an if / else statement to help but it doesn't seem to work.

**Javascript**

```
var time = new Date(Date.now());
var timeHour = time.getHours();
var timeHourFix = timeHour;
var timeMinute = time.getMinutes();
var formatted = timeHourFix + ":" + timeMinute;

if(time.getHours() > 12) {
    timeHourFix = time.getHours() - 12 + "PM";
}else {
    timeHourFix = time.getHours() + "AM";
};

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#hourmin').text(formatted)
});
```

it *should* display the time like `5:35 PM` but it still shows `17:35`

Comment: the accepted answer does not cover the `0030` issue... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/746tqjgz/2/ - see my answer below

Comment: @ArunPJohny what exactly is the `0030` issue, is it that it shows 0 hour instead of 12?

Comment: yes `0030` hours should show the time as `12:30 AM` not as `0:30 AM`

Comment: @ArunPJohny oh you added info about your edit, and I'll test it out (sadly it is very late here and I'm getting to bed right now, so I'll check it out tomorrow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the problem was you were modifying the variable `timeHourFix` after it was appended to the string, there is no live linking between the string and the `timeHourFix` variable so any changes you make to the variable after the string concatenation will not be reflected in the original value.

Also there are multiple other issues like the `AM/PM` should be at the end of the string so that also have to be changed. Also there are other issues with `timeHourFix` like how the value `0030` will be handled, it should be shown as `12:30 AM` not `00:30 AM`

```js
var time = new Date(Date.now());
var timeHour = time.getHours();

//set the hour part
var timeHourFix = timeHour > 12 ? timeHour - 12 : timeHour == 0 ? 12 : timeHour;
var timeMinute = time.getMinutes();
var formatted = timeHourFix + ":" + timeMinute;
//set the AM/PM at the end of the string
formatted += timeHour >= 12 ? ' PM' : ' AM';


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hourmin').text(formatted)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hourmin"></div>
```

Comment: An explanation of what he was doing wrong and what you are suggesting would be helpful.

Comment: @j08691 by the time I answered it, there were so many others with answers so thought of deleting it... but it looks like none of them are still not handling the `0030` issue!!! even the accepted answer which now looks the same as the second most upvoted answer(after edit)

Answer (score 4):

That's because your are declaring the variable `formatted` before the `timeHourFix` is actually modified. Try the code below.

```js
    var time = new Date(Date.now());
    var hour = time.getHours();
    
    var t_hour = hour > 12 ? (hour - 12) : ((hour == 0) ? hour + 12 : hour);
    var formatted = t_hour + " : " + time.getMinutes() + (hour > 11 ? " PM" : " AM");

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#hourmin').text(formatted)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id=hourmin>
```

Comment: This simple change will cause the AM/PM to appear before the ":" in the output....

Comment: @TLS -- sure, but that was not the question

Comment: Yes it was.  The OP says "it *should* display the time like `5:35 PM` but it still shows `17:35`"

Comment: Thank you, and yes I just noticed that it would say `5PM:35`, I will fix that on my own, but this worked. Thanks

Comment: Edited and Updated. Try Now.

Answer (score 3):

The time is not being formatted because the variable `formatted` is being set before `timeHourFix` or `timeHour` is being set. I think it's easiest to set `formatted` in the if else statement directly:

```
var time = new Date(Date.now());
var timeHour = time.getHours();
var timeMinute = time.getMinutes();
var formatted;

if(time.getHours() > 12) {
    formatted = time.getHours() - 12 + ":" + timeMinute + " PM";
} else {
    formatted = time.getHours() + ":" + timeMinute + " AM";
};

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#hourmin').text(formatted)
});
```

Comment: +1 for catching that the AM/PM needs to be moved to the end and for putting  space in there for readability!

Answer (score 0):

Because you set formatted before setting the right values to timeHourFix. Move the assignment of formatted to below the else block.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly working full code.

```js
var time = new Date(Date.now());

var timeHour = time.getHours();

var timeHourFix = timeHour;

var timeMinute = time.getMinutes();

var formatted = timeHourFix + ":" + timeMinute;

if(time.getHours() > 12) {

    time = time.getHours() - 12 + " : " + timeMinute + " PM";

}
else {

    time = time.getHours() +" : " + timeMinute +  " AM";

};


$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#hourmin').text(time)

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<p id="hourmin">Time Display</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always do something like this if you want to simplify your code.

```
var time = new Date(Date.now());
var timeHour = time.getHours();
var timeHourFix = timeHour;
var timeMinute = time.getMinutes();

$(document).ready(function() {
    var timeofday = "";    
    if(timeHour > 12) {
            timeHourFix = timeHour - 12;
            timeofday = "PM";
    }else {
        timeHourFix = timeHour;
        timeofday = "AM";
    };

    var formatted = timeHourFix + ":" + timeMinute + " " + timeofday;

   $('#hourmin').text(formatted)
});
```